# If 90% of the customers has life insurance and 80 % has motor insurance, how many have both?

Tags: probability

An insurance company has only two types of insurances, life and motor. If we know that 80 % of the policy holders has life insurance and 90 % has motor insurance, is it possible to calculate what fraction of policy holders that owns both types of insurances?

I want to check if my attempt is correct: 
Denote $L$ - has life insurance, 
       $M$ - has motor insurance. 
$$ 1 =  P(L \cup M) = P(M) + P(L) - P(M \cap L ) = 1,7 - P(M \cap L). $$
Hence, 70 % of the policyholders has both insurances.

Comment: Yes, your calculation is correct given the assumption that every policy holder has at least one of life or motor insurance (*which is implied in the problem statement from the line "has only two types of insurances"*).  If this hypothesis is dropped however and the insurance company offers a third (or more) type of insurance (e.g. homeowner's insurance), then there would not be enough information to answer, but we could bound it between $0.7$ and $0.8$  (*$0.7$ given your calculations already done, and $0.8$ since it is the lesser of the two percentages given*)

Comment: Yeah, I guess I want to emphasize that assumption when writing out the solution. Also, as mentioned below I can clearly elaborate a little bit on the solution. But I was mainly interested in that I wasn't making some silly errors.

Comment: Not that it makes a big difference but the you switched the percentages from the heading to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer looks right but I'm having trouble following the work, what with the comma and the 7.

$$ P(M\cap L) = P(M) + P(L) - P(M\cup L),$$
where $P(M) = 0.9$ and $P(L) =0.8$.  Also, $P(M \cup L) = 1$ because there are only two types of insurance.  Plug in these values to get the answer.

Comment: Several European countries use a comma the same way that Americans (and other countries) use a period.  $1,7 = 1+7\cdot 10^{-1}$, meaning the same as $1.7$ that you might be more used to seeing.

Comment: @JMoravitz Right, thanks, didn't even cross my mind in this context for some reason.  That clears it all up.

Answer (score 0):

Unless we know that every person in the sample space has **at least one** of the two insurances, we cannot determine the answer.

However, if we *do* know this fact, then we can apply basic Principle of Inclusion / Exclusion to determine that $90\% + 80\% - 100\% = \boxed{70\%}$ of the customers have both.

Comment: I didn't notice this at first, but we do know that everybody has at least one of the two insurances, because the population in the question is specifically the policy holders supplied by the insurances company.  They are, by definition, the people with at least one of the types of insurance.

Comment: That makes sense. That's what I was thinking as well, but as I am not familiar with "policy holders," I didn't want to take any risks. You couldn't solve the problem otherwise.